# Notice: Undefined index: user_id

Tags: php

someone can help me. im geting error with code

Notice: Undefined index: user_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\public\s_game\login\gamelogin.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: user_pass in D:\xampp\htdocs\public\s_game\login\gamelogin.php on line 15

and here code

```
<?php
require '../config.php';

function antiinjection($str) {
    $banwords = array ("'", ",", ";", "--");
    if ( preg_match( "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $str ) ) {
        $str = str_replace ( $banwords, '', $str );
    } else {
        $str = NULL;
    }
    return $str;
}

$user_id = antiinjection($_GET['user_id']);
$user_pass = antiinjection($_GET['user_pass']);

$connInfo = array(
    'Database' => $db,
    'UID' => $user,
    'PWD' => $pass
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connInfo);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Account WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE UserId = ? AND Activated = 1";

$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($user_id), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

if (sqlsrv_num_rows($res)>0)
{

    
    $sql = "SELECT isUserCreated,Password,ID,UserKey,Email,BlockedEndDate FROM Account WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE UserId = ?";
    $r2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($user_id), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    sqlsrv_fetch( $r2 );
    $userPass = sqlsrv_get_field($r2, 1);

    $ID = sqlsrv_get_field($r2,2);
    $userKey = sqlsrv_get_field($r2,3);
    $email = sqlsrv_get_field($r2,4);
    $sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), BlockedEndDate) FROM Account WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE UserId = ?";
    $r3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($user_id), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    sqlsrv_fetch( $r3 );
    if (sqlsrv_get_field($r3,0) >= 0)
    {
        $result = -100;
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE Account SET Blocked = 0 WHERE UserId = '$user_id'";
        sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($user_id), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
        $result = 0;
    }
    $result = sqlsrv_get_field ($r2,0);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
else
{
    $result = -99;
}

if (($result == -100) || ($result == -99))
{
    echo '2';
    die();
```

}

?>

Comment: Do you have `user_id` and `user_pass` in the query string? Also, is this actually part of a Laravel/Zend application?

Comment: information is not enough to understand the question

Comment: First return $_GET and log that and check if the user_id index exists and is being passed through to your page. your $_GET probably has no information

Comment: I've removed the laravel and zend tags because the question you are asking does not seem to relate to any feature provided by either of these frameworks.

Comment: _Side notes:_ Don't send user id and pass in GET requests, use post, or the password will be visible in clear text in your browser history. And what's the point of the `antiinjection()` function? It seems like very bad and unnecessary function. You're basically only allowing passwords to be alpha numerics.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't pass `user_id` and `user_pass` in your GET request. GET request has the parameters in a URL, so you are maybe passing them with POST request.